# Version mismatch troubleshooting - CentOS, EC2, php, php-pdo - SSL disabled

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, amazon-ec2, ssl

On my production server SSL has stopped working. Everything redirects to http:// from https://

The server is a virtual EC2 instance running in AWS. It's their image running CENTOS and PHP5.3, connecting to mysql.

Previously SSL was working perfectly, leading me to believe my CERT files and httpd.conf file is correct.

UPDATE 20 FEB

I've eliminated the other error log messages and discovered another two that seem relevant.
From SSL_ERROR_LOG
`[Wed Feb 20 04:01:02 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) ip-10-204-201-62 does NOT match server name!?`
From apache ERROR_LOG
`[Tue Feb 19 16:01:02 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled`

Below is my httpd.conf entries:
`<VirtualHost *:80>`
`ServerAdmin account@domain.com`
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain-com`
`ServerName www.domain.com`
`</VirtualHost>`

`NameVirtualHost *:443`

`<VirtualHost *:443>`
`ServerName www.domain.com`
`DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain-com`
`SSLENGINE on`
`SSLCertificatekeyFile /etc/httpd/keys/private.key`
`SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/crts/public.crt`
`SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/crts/intermediate.crt`
`</VirtualHost>`

INITIAL PASTE
There is an error in my apache logs:
/etc/httpd/logs/error_log
`[Tue Feb 19 16:01:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...

[Tue Feb 19 16:01:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_dblib.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_dblib.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_register_driver in Unknown on line 0

[Tue Feb 19 16:01:02 2013] [notice] SSL FIPS mode disabled

[Tue Feb 19 16:01:02 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.3.20 mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0j-fips configured -- resuming normal operations`

Googling shows that this error is often caused by version mismatches.
`$ php -v

PHP 5.3.20 (cli) (built: Jan  2 2013 18:43:35) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group

Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by ionCube Ltd., and

    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans`

Unfortunately I don't have the experience to determine exactly which version of which package might be mismatched if that is, in fact, the issue.

Comment: How did you install PHP and the DBLIB module? If from RPMs, which repositories?

Comment: I use yum to install all packages. e.g. sudo yum install php, etc. hth.

Comment: Since things have stopped working, assuming that CERT files and esp. httpd.conf is correct is not a good idea.  Something must have changed to cause things to stop working.  SSL.conf and httpd.conf configuration lines are required to help with answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<VirtualHost>` entries don't contain any redirects, so the redirect must be originating elsewhere. Check the web application and configure it appropriately. Also check any other parts of your setup, such as a load balancer or reverse proxy which you forgot to mention.

(The fact that PHP is unable to load a module isn't relevant to the redirection problem.)

Comment: Nothing of the above was unmentioned. Here is the redirect code:  `// rewrite base URL to SSL if accessed via SSL`  
`if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] == "443" or (isset($_SERVER['https']) and $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) {`  
 `$config['base_url'] =`   `str_replace('http://','https://',$config['base_url']);`  
`}`

Comment: I'm starting to agree it's an application, and not server, issue. I created a new EC2 instance with just apache loaded and with a simple index.html. I then loaded apache similarly*. I pointed the prod domain to it. I then manually browsed to it with forcing https:// (prepending it to the URL). The cert validated perfectly.

Comment: Additionally I set `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off'` and now it goes to http as expected. However, if I then edit the url to https the SSL again loads fine and validates. Heavily leaning towards it being application related.